# Flutter custom shaped button widget

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, custom-painter

[image: Custom shaped]

Hi, I'm converting a html/css design into a dart code to build this custom button-shaped widget. I think some skills in painter is required. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `BeveledRectangleBorder` to obtain this shape:-

```
Material(
            clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
            color: Colors.black,
            shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                topLeft: Radius.circular(30),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(30),
              ),
            ),
            child: Container(
              alignment:Alignment.center,
              height: 80,
              width: 180,
              color:Colors.black,
              child: Text("Apply now",style:TextStyle(color:Colors.white)),
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

To design this kind of shape you need to work with `CustomPainter`.Have a look at [this](https://github.com/TheAlphamerc/flutter_hack20_cyber_theme) repo, It has custom designed button. To be specific [ShapePainter](https://github.com/TheAlphamerc/flutter_hack20_cyber_theme/blob/master/lib/painters/shape_painter.dart)  class is what you are looking for.

Comment: no really, it should be done with `ButtonStyle.shape` property, the docs say: *"The shape of the button's underlying Material.

This shape is combined with side to create a shape decorated with an outline."*

Comment: Can you share some doc reference where this shape is defined ?

Comment: it is defined [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/f9c825981c/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/button_style.dart#L196)

Comment: Yeah, I got that but I don't see any Shape property which can be used to achieve required shape.

Comment: every button has individual `style` property, also you can use a theme for all the buttons like, `TextButtonTheme`, `OutlinedButtonTheme` etc

Answer (score -1):

To make custom shaped buttons in Flutter, provide your shape in the `shape` attribute of your button's `style`.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        shape: const MyShapeBorder(),
        primary: Colors.myColor
    ),
    onPressed: () {
        doSomething();
    },
    child: Text("My Button")
)
```

You can use any of the Material buttons this way.

Your `MyShapeBorder` class needs to override `getInnerPath()`, `getOuterPath()`, `paint()`, `scale()`, and `copyWith()`. You can extend `OutlinedBorder`.

Make sure not to forget to center your shape so that text appears properly inside!